# Jenkins Pipeline post is not honoring stage level pass when earlier stage failed within the catchError step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline where I am doing deployment, running automated tests and then posting the results to the Test Management System.

If Deploy stage fails, I don't want to go ahead with *Run Tests* and *Post Results* stages.

If *Run Tests* fail, I still want to go ahead and post the pass + failed test results to the Test Management System.

On each stage, I want to trigger an email that the respective stage failed.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'my-agent' }
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                // carry out deployment
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    // send email that deployment failed
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    // carry out run
                }
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    // send email that run tests failed
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Post Results') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    // post the results to the test management system
                }
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    // send email that posting results encountered error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem:

The email triggers for *Deploy* and *Run Tests* are working fine. However, when *Run Tests* has failures; even though the results are successfully posted to the Test Management System, the control is entering into failure part of the post for *Post Results* stage.

I tried making the `buildResult` as SUCCESS and `stageResult` as FAILURE. However, the control is not going into the failure part of even the same stage.

What changes do I need to make to avoid sending email for the *Post Test* failure even if it passes but the earlier *Run Tests* has failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not ideal solution. But I have solved the above issue by shifting the post results error email trigger from the post section to a separate stage.

The post result execution stage has `touch import_success` statement at the end. It gets executed only when the posting of results is successful.

The post results error email trigger stage has a when clause to check existence of the import_success file to send the email (trigger email when import_success file doesn't exist).

Here is the final pipeline,

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'my-agent' }
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                // carry out deployment
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    // send email that deployment failed
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    // carry out run
                }
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    // send email that run tests failed
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Post Results') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    // post the results to the test management system
                    sh 'touch import_success'  // this is executed only when post results is successful
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('Post Results Error Email Trigger') {
            when {
                not {
                    expression {
                        fileExists 'import_success'
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                // send email that posting results encountered error
            }
        }
    }
}
```